# Is there a simple RegEx for a string WITH or WITHOUT surrounding CHAR?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to figure out how to improve my current RegEx. Right now I use something like `#?string#?` to match a string whether surrounded by `#` or not. Sadly this matches all 4 variations where I only want it to match 2:

```
#string# : matched
#string  : matched – but I don't want it to
 string# : matched – but I don't want it to
 string  : matched
```

**How can I make the closing `#` depending on the existence of the opening `#`?**

I know that I could go for `(#string#|string)` but my `string` is a rather complex RegEx containing several `()` groups and I want to avoid checking which of the encapsulated groups matched depending on a string with or without the `#` enclosure.

Comment: I think you could go for `#string#|(?<!#)string(?!#)`, not `(#string#|string)`. Why not build the pattern from a variable? It will be still "short" and readable, no need to manually write the dupe parts.

Answer (score 4):

Please, try this pattern. First, capture either `#` or `space` then use that at the end as a back reference

```
([# ])string\1
```

Comment: It won't work if there is a space before and no space after `string`.

Comment: That's right but the given example with the question shows spaces at both end.

Comment: Yeah, let's see. Hope he can figure out what he needs :)

Comment: It is just formatting for us to see the sample words. Your solution is unlikely to work given the question details.

Comment: Hope, @daniel can enlighten us on that part.

Comment: I've aligned the examples just for improved readability. The concrete RegEx is much more complex than my example from above. It has grown over the years and I'm close to throw all away and start a real parser.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @minhazur's answer, you can do the following to search for surrounding groups:

```
((#)|(@))string\1
```

this will recognize `#string#` and `@string@`, however, this will not work for detecting whether there's no matching character... (i.e. `string`)

This would be captured in something like:

```
((#)|(?!#))string\1
```

But this would still match `#string` and `string#`.

**EDIT**

Actually, `((#)|(?!#))string\1` will match the correct thing (matched string between []):

```
#string# --> Matches [#string#]
string   --> Matches [string]
#string  --> Matches #[string]
string#  --> Matches [string]#
```

Take a look at [FreeFormatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output) to check your regex's.